# Definition of electricity

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits

I've seen 'electricity' being used in multiple contexts. Some books call it energy, some call it a branch of physics or electric current or charge(ie positive and negative electricity). I am new to the subject so can somebody please tell me the appropriate definition of electricity ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Electricity is the presence and motion of electric charge. if there is an electric charge, it produces and electric field. The movement of electroc charge is the electric current and produces a magnetic field.